# Cast UITestControl to AutomationElement

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Using the below code (for example) I can cast AutomationElement to UITestControl

```
AutomationElement e = AutomationElement.FromHandle(Window.WindowHandle);
UITestControl u = UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement(e, "UIA");
```

But how can I do it other way round i.e. 
How to cast a UITestControl to AutomationElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across this myself. You should be able to simply use the following:

```
AutomationElement ae = u.NativeElement as AutomationElement;
```

But be careful to reference the correct assembly in your project - I had issues when referencing UIAutomationClient and had to reference UiaComWrapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
AutomationElement ae = u.NativeElement as AutomationElement;
```

It's works only with WPF control.
For Win32 control, `NativeElement` returns `IAccessible` com object.